# Why post processing method is not called?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I am trying to save file at two different location. I want to return success to the client when file is saved at any location successfully. Two tasks(t1,t2) are destined to do this. Following are the cases I have identified:

In case t1 saves successfully then return the response to client and continue with t2. At later stage of T2, If t2 cannot save file then call postprocessing to process t2 data.

But if t1 is unable to save successfully then wait for t2 to finish , now if t2 saves successfully , then postprocess t1 data.

If both t1 and t2 are unable to save then return fail.

In short to return success one of them have to save it successfully and if its just one saves successfully then postprocess the failure one.

I have launched two tasks and waiting for one to be completed. Rest could be easily deciphered by code, in case you need more details , please let me know. I am copying the code from console application, not from actual application. Hence  response is commented in main method.

```
// dummy class used for returning response
public class TaskResult
{
    public int status { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //destination folder
        var desFolders = new List<string>
        {
            @"\\Files\00a807b3\013413a0\012216ad",
            @"\\Files\00a807b3\013413a0\012216ad\IdoNotExist" // to trigger failure case, IdoNotExist => does not exist
        };

        //base 64 string
        var content =
            "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8z8BQDwAEhQGAhKmMIQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";

        var t1 = Task.Run(() => WriteFile(desFolders[0], content));
        var t2 = Task.Run(() => WriteFile(desFolders[1], content));

        // to track if file was ever saved
        bool anySuccess = false;

        int result = Task.WaitAny(t1, t2);

        if (result == 0)
        {
            var response = t1.Result;
            if (response.status == 1)
            {
                anySuccess = true;
                t2.ContinueWith(prevTask =>
                {
                    var t2Res = prevTask.Result;
                    if (t2Res.status == 0) // post processing if t2 could not save file
                        PostProcessing("t2");
                });
            }
        }
        else if (result == 1)
        {
            var response = t2.Result;
            if (response.status == 1)
            {
                anySuccess = true;
                t1.ContinueWith(prevTask =>
                {
                    var t1Res = prevTask.Result;
                    if (t1Res.status == 0)
                        PostProcessing("t1"); // post processing if t1 could not save file
                });
            }

        }


        // to check if completed task was not a success then wait for other running task 
        if (!anySuccess)
        {
            TaskResult waitedResponse = null;
            if (result == 0)
            {
                t2.Wait(); // wait for t2 as t1 was already completed
                waitedResponse = t2.Result;
                if (waitedResponse.status == 1)
                {
                    //if t2 was successful then post process t1
                    anySuccess = true;
                    t1.ContinueWith(prevTask => { PostProcessing("t1"); });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                t1.Wait();
                waitedResponse = t1.Result;
                if (waitedResponse.status == 1)
                {
                    //if t2 was successful then post process t1
                    anySuccess = true;
                    t2.ContinueWith(prevTask =>
                    {
                        var val = prevTask;
                        PostProcessing("t2");
                    });
                }
            }

        }

        if (!anySuccess)
        {
            //return failure;  
        }

        //return success


    }

    private static void PostProcessing(string t)
    {
        Console.WriteLine( $"post processing : {t}");
        Console.ReadLine();
        // insert record in database 
        // intentionally just not to make complex no argument is recived  for insertion
    }

    private static TaskResult WriteFile(string folder, string content)
    {
        var imageName = $"{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}.jpg";
        var fullName = $@"{folder}\{imageName}";

        try
        {
            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(content);
            using (var imageFile = new FileStream(fullName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                imageFile.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                imageFile.FlushAsync();
            }

            return new TaskResult { status = 1 };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new TaskResult { status = 0 };
        }
    }

}
```

Here PostProcessing method is never called though I see there is a failure while saving to non-existing location. How could I refactor this code to make it work?

Comment: `though I see there is a failure while saving to non-existing location` What happens if you fix that bug to save to an existing location?

Comment: When you debugged through it, what was the value of `response.status`? What does that tell you?

Comment: What a mixed logic...  You should simplify this.  I believe you just get lost in what you want to achieve.  This code is so obscure it hurts

Comment: @mjwills: If I provide a valid location then status is 1.

Comment: @mjwills:"When you debugged through it, what was the value" ? in which case in case of valid its 1 , against non existent it is 0.

Comment: So, `status` was 0. In which case the code is doing exactly what you told it to do. You told it to **only** do postProcessing if it was `1`. Honestly, I think you need to debug through the code, line by line, and watch what it is doing.

Comment: @mjwills: You are absolutely correct !   Console.ReadLine(); was missing in main method and program used to exit abruptly before it could post process.

Comment: WriteFile() is basically what I gave you in the previous question, but it's completely broken now because you removed the all-important `await`. This causes the logic to assume the write and flush operations were successful, when in fact the status of those calls is never observed.

Answer (score 0):

Your WriteFile method should be `async` + `Task<TaskResult>` as a return value, since you're using `WriteAsync`.

Also you should `await` `WriteAsync` as it's a task-based method